# External hive table with partition - permission error when i add partition with the data having read access

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

i am getting the below error :

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied:
```

when I try to external create a hive table with data in the hdfs.

I just have the read access and not write access, is that a problem?

Comment: yes , you need write access on that directory as hive expects that you would load data into it after the DDL action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need write access to create external table in hive. then if you are using dynamic partition then you have to enable dynamic partition true. for that use below code.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
```